# "Split" an application on an embedded system

Tags: c, embedded, metering

Actually I'm working on an embedded project which does electrical metering. One requirement is, to split the application in two different parts:

- metrological part (gets certiefied and "frozen")
- user application part (for in-/output tasks; will be updated from time to time to meet future requirements)

The whole application has to reside in the internal FLASH of the controller.
Another requirement is, that each part has it's own checksum that must  be displayed.

This requirements are given by the authorities - the technical solution is my challenge.

Does there exist a "best pratice" for such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is just to ensure that you have a MCU with several flash banks. Store the certified part in one bank, and the rest elsewhere. If you are lucky, you can then have the flash programmer or similar tool generate the checksum and burn them into the same flash bank. This way you could program the "frozen" part separately from the application part, and even update the application without touching the "frozen".

I think the above would be the best practice. Otherwise, it gets much trickier, if you have to calculate the checksums on-chip. You'll have to write the CRC code and a flash burner driver etc.

So check what flash banks there are on your MCU to see if this is possible. Then check with the flash programmer tool vendor how they can help with generating a CRC, probably some CRC-32.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do.  Any communication between the apps can be handled by software interrupts.

Comment: @MartinJames just write your own bootloader/flasher you do not need banks or anything like this.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow this path (own bootloader) because my controller anyway have only "plane" memory - seems to be the most portable solution too

Comment: @P__J__ I've written such applications several times, where the firmware itself calculated CRC on various other parts, then burn the checksum to their respective parts. Apart from all the pain with flash drivers and different banks, you get the problem that cannot know the checksum until the program is executed. And so the checksum calculation must handle the first time execution case differently. Etc. Works best if you can store the code in data flash. Overall, to have a flash programming tool handle all of this instead is so much easier.

Comment: @Lundin  person with with your experience should have understood my comment. The CRC is appended to the binary file with the app image during the build process not after the upload to the target. So the procedure is: compilation -> linking -> bin file extraction -> CRC calculation (and CRC bin file append) -> (optional encryption) -> (optional file CRC calculation)

Comment: @P__J__ To me, "bootloader" is firmware code executed on-chip, so no I didn't understand your comment. What you describe is a good alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own bootloader which will take care about the both applications.

To generate the CRC just write small program which will execute as the post build event and append the CRC to the generated binary file (you do not need to ask your programmer provider for it).

Here you have an example CRC function using the STM32 CRC algorithm.

```
static const uint32_t crctab[256] =
{
        0x00000000,
        0x04c11db7, 0x09823b6e, 0x0d4326d9, 0x130476dc, 0x17c56b6b,
        0x1a864db2, 0x1e475005, 0x2608edb8, 0x22c9f00f, 0x2f8ad6d6,
        0x2b4bcb61, 0x350c9b64, 0x31cd86d3, 0x3c8ea00a, 0x384fbdbd,
        0x4c11db70, 0x48d0c6c7, 0x4593e01e, 0x4152fda9, 0x5f15adac,
        0x5bd4b01b, 0x569796c2, 0x52568b75, 0x6a1936c8, 0x6ed82b7f,
        0x639b0da6, 0x675a1011, 0x791d4014, 0x7ddc5da3, 0x709f7b7a,
        0x745e66cd, 0x9823b6e0, 0x9ce2ab57, 0x91a18d8e, 0x95609039,
        0x8b27c03c, 0x8fe6dd8b, 0x82a5fb52, 0x8664e6e5, 0xbe2b5b58,
        0xbaea46ef, 0xb7a96036, 0xb3687d81, 0xad2f2d84, 0xa9ee3033,
        0xa4ad16ea, 0xa06c0b5d, 0xd4326d90, 0xd0f37027, 0xddb056fe,
        0xd9714b49, 0xc7361b4c, 0xc3f706fb, 0xceb42022, 0xca753d95,
        0xf23a8028, 0xf6fb9d9f, 0xfbb8bb46, 0xff79a6f1, 0xe13ef6f4,
        0xe5ffeb43, 0xe8bccd9a, 0xec7dd02d, 0x34867077, 0x30476dc0,
        0x3d044b19, 0x39c556ae, 0x278206ab, 0x23431b1c, 0x2e003dc5,
        0x2ac12072, 0x128e9dcf, 0x164f8078, 0x1b0ca6a1, 0x1fcdbb16,
        0x018aeb13, 0x054bf6a4, 0x0808d07d, 0x0cc9cdca, 0x7897ab07,
        0x7c56b6b0, 0x71159069, 0x75d48dde, 0x6b93dddb, 0x6f52c06c,
        0x6211e6b5, 0x66d0fb02, 0x5e9f46bf, 0x5a5e5b08, 0x571d7dd1,
        0x53dc6066, 0x4d9b3063, 0x495a2dd4, 0x44190b0d, 0x40d816ba,
        0xaca5c697, 0xa864db20, 0xa527fdf9, 0xa1e6e04e, 0xbfa1b04b,
        0xbb60adfc, 0xb6238b25, 0xb2e29692, 0x8aad2b2f, 0x8e6c3698,
        0x832f1041, 0x87ee0df6, 0x99a95df3, 0x9d684044, 0x902b669d,
        0x94ea7b2a, 0xe0b41de7, 0xe4750050, 0xe9362689, 0xedf73b3e,
        0xf3b06b3b, 0xf771768c, 0xfa325055, 0xfef34de2, 0xc6bcf05f,
        0xc27dede8, 0xcf3ecb31, 0xcbffd686, 0xd5b88683, 0xd1799b34,
        0xdc3abded, 0xd8fba05a, 0x690ce0ee, 0x6dcdfd59, 0x608edb80,
        0x644fc637, 0x7a089632, 0x7ec98b85, 0x738aad5c, 0x774bb0eb,
        0x4f040d56, 0x4bc510e1, 0x46863638, 0x42472b8f, 0x5c007b8a,
        0x58c1663d, 0x558240e4, 0x51435d53, 0x251d3b9e, 0x21dc2629,
        0x2c9f00f0, 0x285e1d47, 0x36194d42, 0x32d850f5, 0x3f9b762c,
        0x3b5a6b9b, 0x0315d626, 0x07d4cb91, 0x0a97ed48, 0x0e56f0ff,
        0x1011a0fa, 0x14d0bd4d, 0x19939b94, 0x1d528623, 0xf12f560e,
        0xf5ee4bb9, 0xf8ad6d60, 0xfc6c70d7, 0xe22b20d2, 0xe6ea3d65,
        0xeba91bbc, 0xef68060b, 0xd727bbb6, 0xd3e6a601, 0xdea580d8,
        0xda649d6f, 0xc423cd6a, 0xc0e2d0dd, 0xcda1f604, 0xc960ebb3,
        0xbd3e8d7e, 0xb9ff90c9, 0xb4bcb610, 0xb07daba7, 0xae3afba2,
        0xaafbe615, 0xa7b8c0cc, 0xa379dd7b, 0x9b3660c6, 0x9ff77d71,
        0x92b45ba8, 0x9675461f, 0x8832161a, 0x8cf30bad, 0x81b02d74,
        0x857130c3, 0x5d8a9099, 0x594b8d2e, 0x5408abf7, 0x50c9b640,
        0x4e8ee645, 0x4a4ffbf2, 0x470cdd2b, 0x43cdc09c, 0x7b827d21,
        0x7f436096, 0x7200464f, 0x76c15bf8, 0x68860bfd, 0x6c47164a,
        0x61043093, 0x65c52d24, 0x119b4be9, 0x155a565e, 0x18197087,
        0x1cd86d30, 0x029f3d35, 0x065e2082, 0x0b1d065b, 0x0fdc1bec,
        0x3793a651, 0x3352bbe6, 0x3e119d3f, 0x3ad08088, 0x2497d08d,
        0x2056cd3a, 0x2d15ebe3, 0x29d4f654, 0xc5a92679, 0xc1683bce,
        0xcc2b1d17, 0xc8ea00a0, 0xd6ad50a5, 0xd26c4d12, 0xdf2f6bcb,
        0xdbee767c, 0xe3a1cbc1, 0xe760d676, 0xea23f0af, 0xeee2ed18,
        0xf0a5bd1d, 0xf464a0aa, 0xf9278673, 0xfde69bc4, 0x89b8fd09,
        0x8d79e0be, 0x803ac667, 0x84fbdbd0, 0x9abc8bd5, 0x9e7d9662,
        0x933eb0bb, 0x97ffad0c, 0xafb010b1, 0xab710d06, 0xa6322bdf,
        0xa2f33668, 0xbcb4666d, 0xb8757bda, 0xb5365d03, 0xb1f740b4
};

static uint32_t crc;

void CrcInit(void)
{
        crc = 0xffffffff;
}



uint32_t CortexCrc(uint8_t *src, size_t len)
{
        uint8_t *bp;
        size_t idx;

        for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
                bp = src + (idx ^ 0x3);
                crc = (crc << 8) ^ crctab[((crc >> 24) ^ *bp) & 0xFF];
        }
        return crc;
}
```